# Google Apps Script HTML Form Won't Submit

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

First I will provide you with the code and briefly explain what it is I am trying to accomplish.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu("Custom Menu")
      .addItem("Show sidebar", "showSidebar")
      .addToUi();
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("entry");
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("entry")
      .setTitle("My custom sidebar")
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function EnterData(fobject) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.activate();

    ss.toast("Something Happened");

  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  range.setValue("It worked");
}

function ProgramSuccess() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast("Program Run Complete");
}
```

**entry.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent form from submitting
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function FormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSucessHandler(FormSuccess).EnterData(formObject);
      }
      function FormSuccess() {
        google.script.run.ProgramSuccess;
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="entryForm" onsubmit="FormSubmit(this)">
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <br>
      Client Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="clientname">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The purpose of this program is to open a sidebar in a google sheet that displays an html page that has a form (tag). Then when you click submit in the html sidebar, it should run the `EnterData` function in Code.gs. My problem is that this function is not being ran and nothing happens when I click the submit button.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**entry.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent form from submitting
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function FormSubmit() {
        google.script.run.withSucessHandler(FormSuccess).EnterData(document.getElementById("entryForm"));
      }
      function FormSuccess() {
        google.script.run.ProgramSuccess;
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="entryForm">
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <br>
      Client Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="clientname">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="FormSubmit()">
      <input type="reset">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, i did not understand why are you passing the **"entryForm"** object to the **EnterData** function because you don't seem to be making use of it.

Comment: I was planning on using the values the user enters into the form like so: `range.setValue(fObject.name);`            I added in your edits though and it still seems like I can't get the HTML to call the server-side functions.

Comment: You have made a spelling mistake in the file **entry.html**. It should be `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` instead of `google.script.run.withSucessHandler`.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you. I guess you can read over your code 10 times and still not find the simplest if mistakes

Comment: Happens with everyone in the beginning. Next time while working with any use case which uses HTML, try using the Inspect Element option in the browser and look for errors in the Console. 99% of times you'll be able to solve the errors on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am still new to using HTML so I will definitely try doing this moving forward

Comment: In `FormSubmit`, why is it necessary to use `EnterData(document.getElementById("entryForm"))` instead of the OP's `formObject`? [Google's own article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#index.html_4) says to do it the OP's way.