# Google Apps Script Server-side Cannot Access File Submitted In A HTMLService Form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, file-upload

I am developing a CSV Importer to accept CSV files provided by any of three providers and convert them to the format required by another piece of software (CoinTracker). The files are uploaded from my local drive using the form I am creating in Google Apps Scripts. The upload commands is accessible from within Google Sheets as an add-on.

The answer to this question must be pretty close to [Google Apps Script HTML Form Won't Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058331/google-apps-script-html-form-wont-submit) since it seems the OP there also was trying to follow [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#index.html_4).

One of the providers is Swissborg which is the one I'm developing first. The problem I'm facing is that, after I pick the file to upload then click Import, nothing happens. I've tried using Logger to pick up any signs of something happening (as you can see in my code). The Executions report doesn't produce a row for `processForm`. The console errors don't seem to be relevant and are:
*There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit* and *GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED*

I'd be grateful for a good answer or troubleshooting advice!

EDIT: Some new info provided at the bottom

#### Code.gs

```
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu(" Import transactions")
    .addItem("Import Swissborg transactions", "importSwissborgCsv")
    .addToUi();
}

function importSwissborgCsv() {
  displayImportDialog();
}

function displayImportDialog() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('importDialog.html')
    .setWidth(480)
    .setHeight(236);
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Import transactions");
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  Logger.log('Processing the form...');
  Logger.log('The object is: ', formObject);

  let formBlob = formObject.file;
  let tempSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create();
  let csv = formBlob.getAs("text/csv");
}
```

#### importDialog.html

```
<html>

  <script>
    function preventFormSubmit() {
      let forms = document.querySelectorAll('importForm');
      for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('importForm', preventFormSubmit);

    function handleFormSubmit() {
      const form = document.getElementById("importForm");
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).processForm(form);
    }

    function onFailure(error) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
      }
  </script>

  <head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="xxx"> -->
  </head>

<body>
  <p>File must be in CSV format</p>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <form id="importForm">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Import" />
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[Link to the Google Sheet I'm working on](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4Skb-wqjO-rF0LiSGr9f-gY1sosEoKWx_x-ZjlJ7uw/edit?usp=sharing)

[Example CSV I'm trying to import](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e4aTOPeLMEPABdaUWtM3lDJp7oU1Oprl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi there @Profplum! I tried to replicate your question, but I wasn't successful. Could you please show the bounded Sheet/Form and how the script is called from it? Feel free to anonymize any personal detail. To better test this script, please share some example CSV files.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Thanks for looking into this :) I updated the question with links to the files.

Comment: After replicating this code I see that the function `handleFormSubmit()` is never called. Could you clarify why?

Comment: That must be the problem, simple as that. The line <form id="importForm"> should be <form id="selectProviderForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()"> Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: I am happy to help you solve this issue by yourself. In order to leave better documentation here, could you please write an answer explaining the solution of this question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as simple as me not specifying what action the form should take upon the submit button being clicked, using the `onsubmit` attribute.

Therefore, the form's HTML is now:

```
<form id="importForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Import" />
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />
</form>
```